# Windows 8.1 Checksum

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, checksum

I've looked all over for the sha-1 or sha-256 checksum for the windows 8.1 iso that you get with the Microsoft’s “Upgrade Windows with only a product key” [page](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/upgrade-product-key-only) but none of the check sums provided on MSDN website matches the one that I were able to get with the download tool. And I've already tried twice and still I get the incorrect hash when compared to the ones provided.

I would either like the correct checksum page from microsoft or other location to obtain the iso of windows 8.1

Comment: with the tool you get a custom ISO which fits to your key so you can't compare the hashes.

Comment: @magicandre1981 I see it makes complete sense when you explain it that way. Thank you also for dragger for pointing this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The upgrade iso and the MSDN subscriber ISO are two different beasts.  As Andre has mentioned, the upgrade download is unique to each individual and the hashes will never match.

If you must have an MSDN hash matching ISO, you'll need to get an MSDN matching subscription or resort to other less than legal means.  FYI, this is not the website where you will find links to that sort of thing.

My advice, just install the ISO you have, it should be fine.

Comment: I was not looking for a less than legal means of obtaining the iso. Nor were I looking to compare the iso that I've got with the tool to MSDN checksums. I was wondering if there were a website in which I would find the checksum for the iso that were created using the tool.

Comment: Then my answer is no.   MSFT does not provide that hash to us, as the upgrade is designed for people who are less technical than us.  But good news, you might be able to find a legal link to the ISO hosted by Microsoft on DigitalRiver and those would have sha1's posted that could be verified.  I don't have links to 8.1, but here is what I have found.  http://superuser.com/questions/78761/where-do-i-download-windows-7-legally-from-microsoft